# R Shiny: Output warning messages to UI

Tags: r, shiny

Warning messsages are output in the console, but how do I get these warnings to appear in the UI so the user can see them without looking at the console?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `tryCatch` to store a warning object.
You can then put the message anywhere on your UI.

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  actionButton("btn", "click me")
)

server <- function(input, output)
{
  observeEvent(input$btn, {
    #x <- (1:3 * 1:2)  # this generates a warning
    #warning("manually generated warning message")
    #mess <- names(last.warning)
    a <- tryCatch(warning(Sys.time()), warning=function(w) { w })
    mess <- a$message
    showNotification(mess)
  })
}

runApp(list(ui=ui, server=server))
```

## Getting both message and value

If the operation is not heavy, an easy way is to run it twice: once with `tryCatch` and the other without.

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  actionButton("btn", "click me")
)

server <- function(input, output)
{
  observeEvent(input$btn, {

    x <- tryCatch(1:3 * 1:2, warning=function(w) { w })
    if (inherits(x, "simpleWarning")) {
      mess <- x$message
      showNotification(mess)
      x <- 1:3 * 1:2
    }
    print(x)
  })
}

runApp(list(ui=ui, server=server))
```

If running the same operation twice is not desirable, then use the following trick ([See this SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3903157/how-can-i-check-whether-a-function-call-results-in-a-warning))

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  actionButton("btn", "click me")
)

server <- function(input, output)
{
  withWarnings <- function(expr) {
    myWarnings <- NULL
    wHandler <- function(w) {
      myWarnings <<- c(myWarnings, list(w))
      invokeRestart("muffleWarning")
    }
    val <- withCallingHandlers(expr, warning = wHandler)
    list(value = val, warnings = myWarnings)
  } 

  observeEvent(input$btn, {
    x <- withWarnings(1:3 * 1:2)
    if (!is.null(x$warnings)) {
      for (w in x$warnings) showNotification(w$message)

    }
  })
}

runApp(list(ui=ui, server=server))
```

Comment: I tried to run your code, but got this message: Warning: Error in observeEventHandler: object 'last.warning' not found

Comment: Really.  Do you see warning message in the console?

Comment: Yeah, the shiny app closes when I press the actionButton, and that warning is in the console.

Comment: Edited my answer.  Can you try this?  And if this is still not working, I would like to see the result of `sessionInfo()`.

Comment: Same issue. Here's my sessionInfo()

`R version 3.4.0 (2017-04-21)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows >= 8 x64 (build 9200)

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252 
[2] LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252   
[3] LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                          
[5] LC_TIME=English_United States.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] compiler_3.4.0 tools_3.4.0 `

Comment: Hmm.  Can you simply type this on console?   `warning("foo"); warnings(); last.warning`.  What do you get?

Comment: That works 

`Warning message:
foo 
Warning message:
foo
$foo
NULL` And if I run the shiny app after I run that line, it works but the notification outputs "foo" so it seems like it's taking whatever exists in the console, not the shiny server

Comment: Edited again.  This time warning message is set to current time.  Does message pop up?

Comment: Say I want to output the result of `x <- (1:3 * 1:2)` Is there a way to show the output from that as well as the warning?

Comment: Figured it out, need to use `finally=` within `tryCatch`. Thanks for your help